# Some times I could login from IIS but some times showing null exception

Tags: c#, oracle

I have an issue while login from iis.

Error is showing in below lines

```
Line 58:             if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
Line 59: {
```

Error is

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Description: An
> unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
> request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
> error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
> set to an instance of an object.
>
> StudForm.Klogin.btn_Login_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\StudForm\RIForm\Klogin.aspx.cs:59
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9767618
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
> eventArgument) +204
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
> eventArgument) +12
> System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
> sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
> System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
> +35 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> +1738

From local host ,it is running fine, but when I access through IIS , it is showing below error some times. What could be the reason.Some times it can access from IIS but some times cannot.

Edit:

```
            vnamtxt.Text = dr["V_NAME"].ToString() -> this v_name is having symbols like (),:,; etc.
```

How can I ignore these symbols while retriving the records so that users could login.

Below is my code:

```
public static DataSet ORSQLSelectRecord(string strselect)

    {

        OracleConnection Ocon = new OracleConnection();
        Ocon.ConnectionString = "User Id=abc;Password=abc;Data Source=ghk";
       
        try
        {
            Ocon.Open();
            OracleCommand ocmd = new OracleCommand();
            ocmd.Connection = Ocon;
            ocmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            ocmd.CommandText = strselect;//
            OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(ocmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            oda.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            Ocon.Close();
            Ocon.Dispose();
           
        }

    }


    protected void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      
        DataSet ds = ORSQLSelectRecord("select* from studDETAILS where USER_NAME = '" + txtUserName.Text + "' and USER_PWD = '" + txtPassword.Text + "' ");
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
            vnamtxt.Text = dr["V_NAME"].ToString();
            string ve_code = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["v_code"]);
            Session["vname"] = vnamtxt.Text;
            Session["vcode"] = ve_code;
           
            Response.Redirect("SumForm.aspx?vcode=" + vendor_code);
            // Response.Redirect("Sum.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            txtPassword.Text = "";
            txtUserName.Text = "";
            lbl_Msg.Visible = true;
            lbl_Msg.Text = "Invalid Login! Please try again";
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to work out why something here is null `ds.Tables[0].Rows` we cant do this for you

Comment: (Possible) side note: Lookup how to use parameterized queries and use those instead of string concatenation to get values in SQL queries. That prevents a lot of funny errors and the vulnerability to SQL injection attacks. Also do not store passwords as plain text. Look up how to salt and hash them.

Comment: Also `catch { return null; }` in `ORSQLSelectRecord()` doesn't seem like good error handling. You just silently return `null`, don't rectify the problem there and don't give the caller any notice on the error. That might well be part of your problem too.